# IDE for perl on remote linux server

Tags: perl, ide, remote-debugging

I have been working remotely with Putty and pgAdmin III to manipulate a PostgreSQL database on a Linux server, but now need to do some heavier lifting to modify Perl and PHP scripts that are used to parse data input files which are submitted to our website.

I would prefer something with robust debugging capabilities.  I know (and love) Eclipse for Java, but don't know if it's an option for Perl/PHP and remote access?  Other suggestions?  It's the "remote" part that has me stuck...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/)?

http://padre.perlide.org/trac/wiki/Features/RemoteEditing

Comment: Seems perlide.org has some issues, link is down.

Comment: Thanks, I will, but their web page seems to be down and I can't tell if Padre is more than a clever text editor.  I should clarify that our web page is written with PHP, but the PHP code calls Perl scripts I need to edit, so I'd really like something that I can step through code with.

Answer (score 2):

If you are comfortable with using Emacs, you can use `cperl-mode` and `tramp` to access the remote files you want to edit. There is support for the Perl debugger (`cperl-db`), but that probably won't seamlessly for a machine accessed via SSH. Another project you might want to look at is [geben](http://code.google.com/p/geben-on-emacs/).

**Update:** Apparently, Emacs' debugger interface is quite [well-integrated](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Remote-processes.html#Remote-processes) with `tramp`.

Comment: Just downloaded Emacs and am a little overwhelmed but intrigued, and it does look like tramp could be very useful if I can get it to work. Thank you!

Comment: Being overwhelmed at first of Emacs is perfectly normal. :-) This will pass.